# How to populate a Vuetify DataTable with axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

i don't know why my tables are not populated with axios, this is my DataTable template, like the documentation:

```
    <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    hide-actions
    class="slideInDown"
  >
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <td>{{ props.item.nombre }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calle }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.numExterior }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.numInterior }}</td>
      <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.codigoPostal }}</td>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

And this is my script:

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
        items: [
         {
           nombre: "",
           calle: "",
           numExterior: "",
           numInterior:"",
           codigoPostal: "",
         }
        ],
    }
  },

  methods:{

     }
created(){

  axios.get('http://localhost:58209/api/GetEstaciones', 
  { 
    headers: 
    {
     "Authorization": "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('token') 
    }
  }).then(response => {
    this.items = response.data;
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response)
  });
},
  mounted(){
      let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      if(token == null){
          this.$router.push('/');
      }
  },

}
</script>
```

But the table is not populated, and when i debugging my WebAPI in Visual Studio it's working the Get method even with Postman. In my script i omit the heders[], i only show the items.

In Postman shows like this:

```
    "calle": "AVENIDA BLA",
    "numExterior": 121,
    "numInterior": 2,
    "codigoPostal": 123456,
    "nombre": "ASDFGGHJKL"
```

Comment: Do you have some error in your console?

Comment: @Hammerbot shows only undefined, but i rewrote my Get method and now it's working.

Comment: axios.get('http://localhost:58209/api/GetEstaciones', {
      headers:{
       "Authorization": "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('token')
          }
  })
    .then(response => { 
      console.log(response)
      this.items = response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response)
        });

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `mounted` : 
[chk the source code of this page](https://qto.fi/prd_qto/list/monthly_issues?pick=id,status,prio,name&page-size=7&page-num=1) ( click on ok with login you with the default demo account ... )

this example has the additional logic [for server side paging](https://github.com/YordanGeorgiev/qto/blob/master/src/perl/qto/templates/controls/list-grid/list-grid.html.ep) and replacing the url params to the back-end , but it might help you grasp the events flow better ...

Short answer ( no error handling, no paging etc. ) :

```
        const vm = new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
            monthly_issues: []
          },
          mounted() {
            // this is the url of the back-end spitting out json
            axios.get("/tst_issue_tracker/select/monthly_issues")
            .then(response => {this.monthly_issues = response.data.dat
            })
          }

        })
```

Long answer:

```
     mounted() {
            var url_params = {} 
         if( window.location.toString().indexOf("?") != -1) {
            window.location.search.split('?')[1].replace(/([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/g, function(m, key, value) {
               url_params[decodeURIComponent(key)] = decodeURIComponent(value);
            });
         } else {
            url_params = { as:"lbls" };  
         }
         this.UrlParams = url_params;
            axios.get((window.location.pathname).replace("/list/" , "/select/") , { params: url_params } )
            .then(response => { 
                this.gridData = response.data.dat ; 
                this.pageSize = url_params['page-size'] || 10 ; 
                this.pageNum = url_params['page-num'] || 1 ; 
            var totalRSsize = response.data.met ; 
            var remainder = totalRSsize % this.pageSize
            var toAdd = 1 // page-size 10 , total-rs-size 30 => 3 and not 4
            if ( remainder == 0 ) { toAdd = 0  }
                this.pagesCount = Math.floor(totalRSsize/this.pageSize ) + toAdd
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                document.getElementById("div_msg").innerHTML="<span id=\"spn_err_msg\">" + error.response.data.msg + '</span>'
            }) 
      }
```